# iOS 11 - SearchController's SearchBar added programmatically gets cut off (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add a `SearchController` to an `UIViewController` programmatically. I got it working but there's one problem which I'm not able to solve, when the `searchBar` is presented, it gets cut off by the `searchResultsTableViewController`. In order to add the `SearchController` programmatically I've used the following code:

```
    // A table view for results.
    UITableView *searchResultsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    searchResultsTableView.dataSource = self;
    searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;

    // Registration of reuse identifiers.
    [searchResultsTableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:Identifier];

    // Init a search results table view controller and setting its table view.
    self.searchResultsTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    self.searchResultsTableViewController.tableView = searchResultsTableView;

    // Init a search controller with its table view controller for results.
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultsTableViewController];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES];
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    // Init search bar frame
    // y = 20 --> offset from NavigationController
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height);

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

    // Add searchBar to scene
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];

    // Change height if OS > iOS 11
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [self.searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:56].active = YES;
    }

    // Enable presentation context.
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    // Call needed to show the searchBar
    [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

When running the app what I get when I present the `searchBar` is this:
[image]

As you can see the `searchResultsTableViewController` covers part of the `searchBar`. Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: The usual thing is to make the search bar the table view's header view.

Comment: @matt Ok thanks! So just by setting it as header its layout should get fixed automatically? Or would I still need to set the `searchBar` frame?

Comment: You need to say `sizeToFit`. Apart from that there should be nothing to do. — The iOS 11 way, on the other hand, is to put the search bar in the navigation bar. (Look at any Apple app, such as Mail, to see what I mean.) But that's another story.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your suggestion! I've edited my implementation and added the `searchBar` as `TableView`'s header and everything worked fine.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for reporting back. Feel free to answer your own question; this might help someone else.